# Facebook check like - FB.Event.subscribe not working anymore if you like FB page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used this to check if user clicked like button:

```
FB.init({
  appId      : 'APP_ID',
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.1'
});
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
    showCoupon('Facebook like')
});
```

This seems to not work properly anymore if:

a) User is not logged in

b) If like url is Facebook page and not your website url

In these cases, it will show Facebook dialog to login/confirm like. Once you login/confirm like, it will close dialog but it won't trigger FB.Event.subscribe

Is anybody else facing the same issue, were there any updates lately and is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user liked something?

Comment: Facebook has restricted features around detecting whether a user likes a specific page in the past already, because it gets abused to much - to “force” people to like a page to get to specific content, or to reward them for giving a like in any other way. Both not allowed, because they create fake likes.

Comment: And even if you only want to know this for a seemingly benign purpose such as “I don’t want to show the like button any more to users who already liked the page” - don’t. I might have liked your page by accident, or at some point decide I don’t like it any more. Giving me the chance to retract my like in the same place where I gave it, is only fair.

Comment: "showCoupon" - sounds indee like you want to give something to the user if he likes your page. which is not allowed, as others have mentioned already. you really need to read the platform policy.